# Access reports: variable height text at the bottom of the page

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2010

I have a Microsoft Access report that is basically a delivery note. At the bottom, right above some fixed text, the note should include delivery instructions of variable length (maybe just a short text, maybe several lines).

I cannot find a way to make this. If I put this instructions field within the page footer with the fixed text, parts of the page footer end up being cut off when printing the report. Automatic height does not work, and there is no CanGrow property for the page footer section.

If I put the field in the details sections, it looks like there is no way to tell Access to vertically align the details section at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Maybe concatenate the variable field with the fixed text. You can force carriage return line feed with Chr(13) & Chr(10).

Comment: Have you tried setting the CanGrow/CanShrink property of the delivery instructions textbox and place it in the footer?

Comment: Yes. The page footer itself does not have those properties. Doing that just pushes the fixed text down when the textbox is big enough.

Comment: What about report footer or a group footer? They have a keep together property.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Kostas k. - Set the Can Grow property of the Text Box to Yes. The Footer will grow to fit the controls in it, so does not need a can grow property. 
If possible ensure there are no other controls at the same height as this control. You can shrink the control to almost zero height and it will expand to allow the text to fit...